# Export List in SharePoint 2007 to List in SharePoint 2010

Tags: list, export, list-template, access

I have a SharePoint 2007 list that I want to copy over to an existing SharePoint 2010 list.
Both of them have the exact same columns.

What is the best way to do this?

I tried opening both of them in Access and then just copy and past the records but it does not want to work.

I even exported the 2007 list to Excel and then tried to import the Excel file to the 2010 list and that did not want to work as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can save the list in SharePoint 2007 with content - you can then save the .stp to the file system and you'll need to open up the .stp file (rename it to cab).  You then need to update the version number within the manifest file from 3 to 4 and recab it.

You can then upload the new .stp to SharePoint 2010 and create your list.

Comment: Manifest file??

Comment: @Etienne this is the manifest.xml file which is compressed within the .stp file.

Comment: In SharePoint 2010, where do I search for the list? I understand the repackaged .stp file goes in the folder _catalogs\lt\

Comment: Just found out I need to repackage with makecab.exe.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this before using Data Sync Studio (use a trial key for one-off sync).

Essentially, do the same as show in this blog entry but rather and Office 365 as the destination use the SP 2010 list.

http://www.simego.com/Blog/2011/06/Office-365-SharePoint-Data-Synchronisation

What might be useful is that you can set the source to the 2007 list and it will create the same list (columns) in 2010 before sync'ing them.

15 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is something you are going to do often or very infrequently.  If often, I would recommend looking at a 3rd party tool.  With Metalogix, for example, you can do this type of operation by simply dragging the list from your 2007 site to your 2010 site...very simple.  Here's a link if you're interested:

http://www.metalogix.com/Products/Migration-Manager-for-SharePoint/SharePoint-Upgrade.aspx

The Excel export/import should work.  What error(s) are you getting when you try that?

Answer (score 0):

Thing to look for in your excel file before uploading as a custom list.

Do you have empty cells in your Excel data? If so fill them with placeholder data, empty cells will cause issues.

Verify your cells only contain text / integers.  To be sure you can select all the content, do a cut operations, then use the Paste-Values operations over the same data.

If you still have problems, you can import it in chunks.  Open your list in datasheet view with all the columns visible that match the exported excel items.  Then just copy chunks of rows into the datasheet from the client.  Eventually, you'll hit the rows that were giving you problems, and you can diagnose what those issues are and correct them or manually enter the data and continue.

Answer (score 0):

I often use access to do this. Export list to access 2007 or 2010. Next publish the table from Access to SharePoint 2010 site. Easy, clean and prior to publishing you can even manipulate, order data.