# How to export a list in SharePoint 2010 and import it into 2013

Tags: powershell, migration, export, import

Is there a good **free** way of exporting a list in SharePoint 2010 and importing it into 2013.

Need to keep structure, data, attachments and other data but revisions, permissions etc not necessary.

I've seen this [question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/17093/export-list-in-sharepoint-2007-to-list-in-sharepoint-2010) which talks about extracting the powershell export file, changing the manifest, re-cabing and then importing but have not tried it yet.

Comment: you can try this one, might work http://spdeploymentwizard.codeplex.com/

Comment: @TimeToShine - the link you gave is for 2010 content migration. Not applicable for this question

Comment: @Andrey Thats the reason I said "it might work" :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Export and Import, you can migrate list from SP 2010 to SP 2013 but you have to make some manual changes.

1. Export the list from SharePoint 2010 using either the Central Administration or PowerShell (Export-SPWeb). In the Central Administration, go to Backup and Restore > Export a site or list. Choose your list, and click Start Export
2. Copy the exported list (.cmp file) to your desktop and change the extension to .cab. You can then extract it using a software like WinRar.
3. Open the SystemData.XML file with an editor like NotePad++ and change the version from 14.0.0.0 to 15.0.0.0 , and the build version from your 14.0.x.x to 15.0.x.x (depending on the build you have on both your farms).
4. Now we have to repackage it as a .cab file. I used a software called CabPack. Select your Source and Destination. Change the CabinetNameTemplate if you want, and click on OK.
5. Change the extension from .cab to .cmp
6. Copy the .cmp file back on the network share or directly on the SharePoint 2013 Server.
   Open SharePoint 2013 Management Shell as an administrator. Run this command by changing the parameters of course!

Import-SPWeb "SiteCollection Name" path c:\backup\Customers.cmp

1. Open up your SharePoint Site and your list should be there.

Comment: What if I had multiple .cmp files on a single list of library? The System.Data.xml file lies in the last file. But when I edited it and tried to import I get the following error:                                                                                        
"[5/30/2017 2:28:44 PM] [Warning] Import requirement file Requirements.xml was not found no verifications ran.
[5/30/2017 2:28:44 PM] [FatalError] [-2147467261] [System.ArgumentNullException] [Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: input]  "

Answer (score 1):

I have used [Gary Lapointe's utilities](http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/downloads/) to move content between farms in the past.  The GUIDs can change so anything tied to that, like web parts, custom features, etc.. might break.  Ironically, I asked Microsoft a few weeks back if they could recommend a full fidelity way to move partial content between farms and they could not.  I found that rather frightening but perhaps expected given the possible complexity in SharePoint.

Comment: Between different versions of SharePoint?

Comment: I have not used it in that capacity directly but it should work as that tool uses its own export/import logic rather than relying on SharePoint.  It should be tested in a Dev/QA environment first though.

Comment: I think he must actually use SharePoints built in ones with a few additions looking at the stack trace of some errors.

Comment: Couldn't get this to work - complained about differing versions (just as the OOTB Import-SPWeb one does) and tried changing Version and Build in SystemData.xml but still didn't import correctly http://moss-arvit.blogspot.co.uk/2010/11/fatalerror-version-of-package-120100-is.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you try the **Export-SPWeb** and **Import-SPWeb** powershell commands??? I don't really know if that works but it is a posibility.

Comment: yes - you can't export one version of SP and import to another.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Export-SPWeb` and `Import-SPWeb` to copy the list to a new 2010 content database on the source server.

1. Create a new site collection. (UI or PowerShell)
2. Export from Source site
3. Import into destination site (All ID's do stay intact)
4. Backup the New 2010 Content database with the list in it.
5. Restore the New 2010 Content database on the SP 2013 SQL server.
6. Mount the 2010 Content database which will upgrade the content database to 2013.

   ```
   Mount-SPContentDatabase -Name 2010ContentDatabase -DatabaseServer SP2013Farm\SharePoint -WebApplication http://sp2013farm/
   ```
7. Upgrade the site collection by Navigating and select Upgrade Site.

If you need the list in an existing site collection you can then export the list in 2013 and import it in to the existing site collection.