# Export document library from SharePoint 2010 with large chunk of data to SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2010, 2013, document-library, export, import

I am migrating my content from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013. The document libraries that I need to migrate has around 10 GB of data. I have tried to export it using the steps specified in [this answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/60615/how-to-export-a-list-in-sharepoint-2010-and-import-it-into-2013) but is did not work for me. I have also tried using the Export and Import command.

None of the above mentioned groups work for me.

I am badly stuck in this issue since long. Please help ASAP.

Comment: What You think about tools? Such as Sharegate Migration Tool http://share-gate.com/

Comment: I have never tried it. Will explore it and give it a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you try with this [copy-sharepoint-lists-and-document](http://get-spscripts.com/2011/10/copy-sharepoint-lists-and-document.html)

You must change version from 14.0.0.0 to 15.0.0.0 , and the build version from your 14.0.x.x to 15.0.x.x (depending on the build you have on both your farms).
Like in [this answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/60615/how-to-export-a-list-in-sharepoint-2010-and-import-it-into-2013) from your question.

I used this for migrating from SharePoint 2007 to 2013.

Comment: For repackaging into .cab i used [this](http://blog.dennus.net/2011/05/17/modify-and-repackage-sharepoint-stp-files/).

Answer (score 2):

Their are 3 ways to copy a list from 2010 to 2013.

1. Database upgrade...take the backup of 2010 database and restore it in 2013 farm then perform the upgrade. at the end you can export the list and import it.
2. using the 3rd party tools( easy ways)...many companies offering free trail(some for 15 days and some for 25GB of data). You can try Share-Gate or metalogix. I used both and so far good experience.
3. Modify the .cmp file( it is not supported by MSFT). Export the List from 2010, make the changes into .cmp file(from 14 to 15), repackage it and import it in 2013. Please read the below blog for complete step by step guide.

[How to move a List from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013](http://absolute-sharepoint.com/2013/08/how-to-move-a-list-from-sharepoint-2010-to-sharepoint-2013.html)

Comment: I have started working using ShareGate. It is working for me but I am still unable to preserve the version history. How can I preserve version history too?